# Equalize lineHeight in a NSAttributedString with different fonts

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a NSAttributedString used to set the attributed text of a UITextView. There are two different fonts depending if a character is Latin or Chinese.
My problem is than the lineHeight attributes are different for each font and it result with two different line spacing in my text view (Depending if there is a Latin character in the line above or not, because the lineHeight of the Latin font is higher than the Chinese font)

So my question : Is there a way to equalize those lineHeight ?

Comment: No I guess, lineHeight is read-only. May be you can go for Core Graphics Text Drawing where you might be able to achieve it.